# Oracle - Should I convert dates with to_date before comparison?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the queries I stumble upon each date is converted with to_date function before any comparison. Sometimes it caused "literal does not match format string" error, which had rather nothing to do with format and the cause was explained here:
[ORA-01861: literal does not match format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387917/ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string)

My question is: is it really necessary to use date conversion? Why is it converted in the first place before applying any logical comparison?

Comment: Please show us the query that generates the error and the table definitions of the tables involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not store dates as, well, dates.  The problem is that there might be a time on the dates that would cause them to be unequal.  (You can see the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847) for information about the date data type.)

In general, we think that "2013-01-01" is equal to "2013-01-01".  However, the first date might be "2013-01-01 01:00:00" and the second "2013-01-01 02:02:02".  And they would not be equal.  To make matters worse, they may look the same when they are printed out.

You don't actually have to convert the dates to strings in order to do such comparisons.  You can also use the `trunc()` function.  Such a transformation of the data is insurance against "invisible" time components of the data interfering with comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be storing dates as actual dates (or timestamps).  If you have strings representing dates, you will often need to convert them using to_date (with a specified format, not relying on default formats).  It really depends on what comparisons/date functionality you want.  You're getting errors because you hit a value that does not conform to your specified format.  This is also a good reason to specify a column as DATE to store dates.  For example,

```
select to_date('123', 'MM-DD-YYYY') from dual;
```

will throw an ORA-01861.  So you may have 99.9% of the rows as MM-DD-YYYY, but the 0.1% will cause you headaches.

Anyway, if you cleanup those strings, you can do much more using to_date and date functions.  For example:

```
select 
(last_day(to_date('02-05-2009', 'MM-DD-YYYY')) - to_date('01-15-1998', 'MM-DD-YYYY')) as days_between_dates
from dual;
```

Not fun to do that with strings.  Or maybe just find the most recent date:

```
select greatest( to_date('02-05-2009', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), to_date('12-01-1988', 'MM-DD-YYYY')) from dual;
```

using string comparison would give wrong answer:

```
select greatest('02-05-2009', '12-01-1988') from dual;
```

Just a few examples, but much better to treat dates as dates, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **string** that *represents* a date, use `TO_DATE`.
If you already have a date, use it directly.

Comment: What I have is a subquery (used for join) where date is converted with to_char, and then in parent query it is used in where clause and is converted with to_date.

Comment: @kyooryu: Why do you convert it with `to_char` in the first place?

Comment: @kyooryu if you have a specific example in mind that raises the question, it would be best to post it as part of the question.

Comment: @David Aldridge - Unfortunately those are work queries so I cannot post them.
Daniel Hilgarth - I want to ask the same question to people who developed it :)

Comment: @kyooryu: If you can't remove the conversion via `to_char` my first line applies: After the sub-query is done, you no longer have a date, you have a string that represents a date, hence you have to use `to_date` with the same format the was specified in `to_char`.

Comment: @kyooryu Nobody is going to steal your work query and use it to hack your system, or infringe your intellectual property rights.

Comment: @David Aldridge - I know, but I doubt my employer would be delighted to see part of the DB schema published online.

Comment: @kyooryu: it's a misconception that a query or the table definitions of just some tables reveal any critical information.

Comment: It's a small price to pay for getting accurate, timely and free help for his staff

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's not really about what seems to be critical information, it is about company policy, which I will not break to get an answer to a question which I asked out of my curiosity, because it does not affect my work in any way.