# Passing date parameter from Unix to Oracle stored procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I am writing a Unix shell script to invoke Oracle stored procedure with a date as an input parameter, but I am getting the following error. Kindly help me how to pass date parameter to Oracle stored procedure from Unix.

The expected date format I need to pass to procedure is:

```
Start Date:       2013-09-12 00:00
End Date  :       2013-09-04 00:00
```

ERROR Which I got while executing Unix script:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
     SQL> SP2-0552: Bind variable "00" not declared.
     SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo " C3 ..." - rest of line ignored.
     SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo "####..." - rest of line ignored.
```

My Unix shell script source:

```
date1='date'
date1=$(/bin/date --date="$date1" -d "+0 day" +"%F")
date1+=" 00:00"
date2=$(/bin/date --date="$date1" -d "-8 day" +"%F")
date2+=" 00:00"
echo "Report Period"
echo "Start Date:       "$date1
echo "End Date  :       "$date2
sqlplus preprdsm/PREPRDSM@pssm <<EOF
execute C3_REPORT($date1,$date2)
echo " C3 REPORT Executed Successfully "
```

My Oracle Stored procedure inputs are:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE C3_REPORT(
START_DATE IN date,
END_DATE IN date)
IS
emesg VARCHAR2(250);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enclose your date values in quotes so that Oracle sees the quotes.

```
sqlplus preprdsm/PREPRDSM@pssm <<EOF
execute C3_REPORT('$date1', '$date2')
echo "C3 report Executed Successfully"
EOF
```

That assumes your NLS settings match the date format.

Comment: Thanks, but the values are going as string and it is not considered as date. I am getting the following exception.

Comment: SQL> BEGIN C3_REPORT('2013-09-12 00:00','2013-09-04 00:00'); END;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: You can look up that error better than I can; I don't have Oracle anywhere.  But I'll not be surprised to find it is saying "I do not understand the format of the date string you've provided", which comes down to the NLS settings I mentioned in the answer.  Or maybe Google plus Stack Overflow will ride to the rescue: [ORA-01861 Literal does not match format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387917/ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string)