# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle, date

i am trying to format a char that looks like : 22122016, to 22/12/2016.

i've used :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('22122016','NLS_DATE_FORMAT = DD/MM/YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

But i am getting date format not recognized, and i don't have the right of settig the NLS_DATE_FORMAT on the format that i want.

i also tried :

```
to_char(to_date(22122016),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

but i get ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Do not specify `NLS_DATE_FORMAT =` in the `to_date()` function. specify format only - `TO_DATE('22122016','DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: You have a string '22122016' and want to convert this to the string '22/12/2016'? Then use string functions. Or do you want to convert your string to a datetime? Or is it simply a fixed date you want to use in your query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01861: literal does not match format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387917/ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string)

Comment: What you are trying do does not makes much sense looking at your example. Why would you want to convert one string to another using to_date function? Function to_date will not convert string to another string - it will convert string to a date, which itself has no format. If you really want to do this you will have to convert to date, and then back to string, specifying format mask in both conversions: select to_char(to_date('22122016', 'ddmmyyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;

Answer (score 4):

As second parameter in `TO_DATE` you need to specify format of data you passed as first parameter so please try:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('22122016','DDMMYYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210) you will find description of allowed formats and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) some documentaion of `to_date` function.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is date literal, this is the ANSI/ISO way -

```
select date '2016-12-22' from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to format a char that looks like : 22122016, to 22/12/2016

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

This happens because you have tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

You can overcome this issue by carrying out following alteration.

```
TO_DATE('22122016','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

This will produce: **22/12/2016**

> As a general rule, if you are using the TO_DATE function, TO_TIMESTAMP
>   function, TO_CHAR function, and similar functions, make sure that the
>   literal that you provide matches the format string that you've
>   specified