# I am getting error while accessing the date query

Tags: java, database, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting this error with this date query :

```
SELECT Y.ITEM_ID
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DOM1.ITEM_ID
        ,COUNT(1)
    FROM (
        SELECT ITEM_ID
            ,COUNT(1)
            ,MAX(ATTRIBUTE_1) ATTRIBUTE_1
        FROM (
            SELECT UNIQUE domain_index.item_id
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN domain_index.ATTRIBUTE_FIELD_ID = 382767
                        THEN DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, NULL, '1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J0K1L2M3N4O5P6Q7R8S9T0U5V4W3X2Y1Z', ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
                    END AS ATTRIBUTE_1
            FROM T_DOMAIN_INDEX domain_index
            WHERE DOMAIN_ID = 64279
                AND (
                    ATTRIBUTE_FIELD_ID = 382767
                    AND (to_date('01 ' || nvl(to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') <> to_date('01 Mar 2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
                    )
            )
        GROUP BY item_id
        ) DOM1
    WHERE (to_date('01 ' || nvl(to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(DOM1.ATTRIBUTE_1), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') <> to_date('01 Mar 2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
        AND (to_date('01 ' || nvl(to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(DOM1.ATTRIBUTE_1), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') <> to_date('01 01 0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
    GROUP BY DOM1.ITEM_ID
    ) Y
    ,T_DOMAIN_ITEM A
WHERE Y.ITEM_ID = A.ITEM_ID
    AND NVL(A.PARENT_ITEM_ID, 0) = 0
    AND A.IS_ARCHIVED = 0
ORDER BY DT_UPDATED DESC
    ,Y.ITEM_ID
```

> Error : ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>   *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>   *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

The attribute value can be a date in ISO format or null or blank. This error is received when one of the attribute value is blank.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, which, by the way, may reveal the syntax error in the process.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Oracle expect but your code

```
SELECT Y.ITEM_ID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
        DOM1.ITEM_ID,
        COUNT(1)
      FROM (SELECT
              ITEM_ID,
              COUNT(1),
              MAX(ATTRIBUTE_1) ATTRIBUTE_1
            FROM (SELECT UNIQUE
                    domain_index.item_id,
                    CASE WHEN domain_index.ATTRIBUTE_FIELD_ID = 382767
                      THEN DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, NULL, '1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J0K1L2M3N4O5P6Q7R8S9T0U5V4W3X2Y1Z',
                                  ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) END AS ATTRIBUTE_1
                  FROM T_DOMAIN_INDEX domain_index
                  WHERE DOMAIN_ID = 64279 AND (ATTRIBUTE_FIELD_ID = 382767 AND (to_date('01 ' || nvl(
                      to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'),
                      '01 0001'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') <> to_date('01 Mar 2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))))
            GROUP BY item_id) DOM1
      WHERE (to_date('01 ' || nvl(
          to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(DOM1.ATTRIBUTE_1), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'),
                     'dd/mm/yyyy') <> to_date('01 Mar 2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) AND (to_date('01 ' || nvl(
          to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(DOM1.ATTRIBUTE_1), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'),
                                                                                         'dd/mm/yyyy') <>
                                                                                 to_date('01 01 0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy'))
      GROUP BY DOM1.ITEM_ID) Y, T_DOMAIN_ITEM A
WHERE Y.ITEM_ID = A.ITEM_ID AND NVL(A.PARENT_ITEM_ID, 0) = 0 AND A.IS_ARCHIVED = 0
ORDER BY DT_UPDATED DESC, Y.ITEM_ID
```

has `to_date` function ans it has different date value and format. for example

```
to_date('01 01 0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

You should replace to

```
to_date('01/01/0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Everywhere in your expression.

Comment: Oracle is actually pretty flexible by default (not always a good thing), and it quite happy with `to_date('01 01 0001', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` and even `to_date('01 Mar 2017','dd/mm/yyyy')`. It would certainly be better to use the right format mask, but that isn't causing this error.

Comment: Oh, then it is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387917/ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string.

Comment: Alex Poole : then what can be the reason for such a behavior , this query works fine if the attribute_value is not null or not empty, let me add this

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from this:

```
DECODE(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE, NULL,
 '1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J0K1L2M3N4O5P6Q7R8S9T0U5V4W3X2Y1Z', ATTRIBUTE_VALUE)
```

When your attribute value is null, you're replacing it with that fixed string, aliased as `ATTRIBUTE_1`. That's in the inline view aliased as `DOM1`.

In the next level out you're filtering on

```
WHERE (to_date('01 ' || nvl(to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(DOM1.ATTRIBUTE_1), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') ...
```

If you put the decoded value into that you are actually doing, or just this part:

```
to_date('01 ' || nvl(to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM(DOM1.ATTRIBUTE_1), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

you're really doing:

```
select to_date(replace(TRIM('1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0J0K1L2M3N4O5P6Q7R8S9T0U5V4W3X2Y1Z'), 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

and that clearly isn't a valid ISO (or any other) date format; hence the ORA-01861 error.

Without knowing why you're using that fixed string in place of a null value, it isn't clear if you should just not be doing that decode, or should be treating that value differently - as an exception in the where clause perhaps. It seems pointless though as it isn't used for anything except the date conversion.

---

Incidentally, you seem to be doing a lot of conversions to and from dates, just to get the first day of the month. Instead of doing something like:

```
select to_date('01 ' || nvl(to_char(to_date(replace(TRIM('2017-03-02T17:04:30'), 'T', ' '),
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Mon YYYY'), '01 0001'), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
from dual;
```

you could do:

```
select nvl(trunc(to_date('2017-03-02T17:04:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'), 'MM'), 
  date '0001-01-01') from dual;
```

You should also be using date format masks consistently, as @DmitryGorkovets pointed out, but you could also use ANSI date literals for the fixed dates, e.g. instead of doing `to_date('01 Mar 2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')` you could do `date '2017-03-01'`.